# hyperlink in amsrefs package miss the last parenthesis

Tags: hyperref, amsrefs

It seems like a bug, I want to fix it but fails. I will describe the problem by the following MME:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage[author-year]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable,
    AUTHOR = {Motazedifard, Ali and Dalafi, A. and Naderi, M. H. and
              Roknizadeh, R.},
     TITLE = {Controllable generation of photons and phonons in a coupled
              {B}ose--{E}instein condensate-optomechanical cavity via the
              parametric dynamical {C}asimir effect},
   JOURNAL = {Ann. Physics},
  FJOURNAL = {Annals of Physics},
    VOLUME = {396},
      YEAR = {2018},
     PAGES = {202--219},
      ISSN = {0003-4916},
   MRCLASS = {81},
  MRNUMBER = {3853390},
       DOI = {10.1016/j.aop.2018.07.013},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2018.07.013},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
In \ocite{MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable}, \citeauthor{MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable} show that ...
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The compile result looks like:
[image: The MME PDF]
It is wired that the color is only for "**In Motazedifard et al. (2018**", why the last "**)**" is out of color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have seen this wrong coloring in some textbooks and now I am convinced that this is a bug in the `amsrefs` package. However (I could be wrong though), it is worth pointing out that rather than “missing the last right parenthesis”, the intended behavior should be “using black/normal colored parentheses while the authors and year are colored”. You can check this by typing

```
\cite{MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable}
```

which will produce a pair of black parentheses.

I can offer a fix which forces the left parenthesis to be black.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage[author-year]{amsrefs}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\citesel@object[5]{\PrintCiteNames{#3} \textcolor{black}{\citeleft}#4}
% The original definition is
% \def\citesel@object#1#2#3#4#5{\PrintCiteNames{#3} \citeleft#4}
% which misses the possible color change by hyperref
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable,
    AUTHOR = {Motazedifard, Ali and Dalafi, A. and Naderi, M. H. and
              Roknizadeh, R.},
     TITLE = {Controllable generation of photons and phonons in a coupled
              {B}ose--{E}instein condensate-optomechanical cavity via the
              parametric dynamical {C}asimir effect},
   JOURNAL = {Ann. Physics},
  FJOURNAL = {Annals of Physics},
    VOLUME = {396},
      YEAR = {2018},
     PAGES = {202--219},
      ISSN = {0003-4916},
   MRCLASS = {81},
  MRNUMBER = {3853390},
       DOI = {10.1016/j.aop.2018.07.013},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2018.07.013},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
In \ocite{MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable}, \citeauthor{MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable} show that ...
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: color fixed]

---

One could also force the right parenthesis to be cyan, like this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage[author-year]{amsrefs}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\cite@cj
  {\citeright}
  {\textcolor{cyan}\citeright}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable,
    AUTHOR = {Motazedifard, Ali and Dalafi, A. and Naderi, M. H. and
              Roknizadeh, R.},
     TITLE = {Controllable generation of photons and phonons in a coupled
              {B}ose--{E}instein condensate-optomechanical cavity via the
              parametric dynamical {C}asimir effect},
   JOURNAL = {Ann. Physics},
  FJOURNAL = {Annals of Physics},
    VOLUME = {396},
      YEAR = {2018},
     PAGES = {202--219},
      ISSN = {0003-4916},
   MRCLASS = {81},
  MRNUMBER = {3853390},
       DOI = {10.1016/j.aop.2018.07.013},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2018.07.013},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
In \ocite{MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable}, \citeauthor{MotazedifardDalafiNaderiRoknizadeh2018Controllable} show that ...
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: color fixed alternatively]

Comment: This fix seems work for the `colorlinks` setting of `hyperref`, but fails when I use `ocgcolorlinks`.